# Is it possible to split excel spreadsheet

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to split a spreadsheet and have 3 columns on the upper half, while having 6 or more on the bottom half?

Comment: You can put anything anywhere; a spreadsheet is not a single table.  This would be obvious if you just try it.  So it isn't clear what you're asking, or what issue you're trying to address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the **"View" tab in the ribbon** at the top of the screen.

Find the item labeled "Split". This will split the worksheet into four quadrants, that can be resized according to taste.

Immediately to the left of the "Split" button, I also recommend trying the "Freeze Panes" button. This allows you to split top and bottom of the screen, freeze selected areas, as well as freeze the first row/column.

[image]